# run shell script on client remotly from server

Tags: node.js, nat-traversal

I have one server and multiple clients. The server wants to run shell script on each device it wants to. Absolutely it's not possible via simple socket because we may have thousands of devices. Also server and devices should be always connected via socket. after a lot of search I found out that the solution might be NAT-T. But still I don't know how to use that or if there is another solution.
Please help me what should I do on clients and server.

Comment: So use ssh on each device? There are nodejs libraries to do that. If you have a socket open (its unclear now if you have or if you don't have), you can use something similar to the child process communication? Why would you use NAT? That sounds more like a network layer issue outside of node. Can or can't you reach the devices from the server or can only the devices reach the server?

Comment: So what is client's address and port? also the address of clients may change. The problem is how I can reach the clients via server.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the clients address and port upfront, you need to connect to the server with the clients. 1000s of devices are no problem. You run in a socket limit around 65000 open ports (check `ulimit`). Build an object stream between client and server and execute the script based on the object the client receives. You could also set an interval on the clients and let them check with simple http(s) every n secs if there is something to do for them?

See for example here: [Node Stream Docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v5.x/docs/api/stream.html)
Or here: [Node HTTP Docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v5.x/docs/api/http.html)

Comment: So what if the number of clients exceeds 65000?

Comment: You need another approach - for example the http. But if you have more than 65000 clients, you might need a real architecture. have a look at some IoT architecture approaches, for example from amazon aws or others...